# Minimising a Family of Error Functions with Usage Constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Suppose we have a known target vector, $T \in \Bbb{R}^n$:

$$
T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
t_1 \cr
t_2 \cr
\vdots \cr
t_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and a known availability vector $A \in \Bbb{R}^m$:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \cr
a_2 \cr
\vdots \cr
a_m
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to be able to generate an m-by-n matrix $X$:

$$
X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & x_{1,3} & \cdots & x_{1,n} \cr
x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & x_{2,3} & \cdots & x_{2,n} \cr
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr
x_{m,1} & x_{m,2} & x_{m,3} & \cdots & x_{m,n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

whose terms minimise the below error functions $\epsilon_k$:

$$
\epsilon_1 = \sum_{j=1}^m x_{j,1} - t_1\\
$$
$$
\epsilon_2 = \sum_{j=1}^m x_{j,2} - t_2\\
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
\epsilon_n = \sum_{j=1}^m x_{j,n} - t_n\\
$$

AND satisfy the below usage constraints:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x_{j,k} <= a_j
$$
$$
\forall j \in [1,m]
$$

ie. The sum of the i-th **column** of matrix X should be as close as possible to the i-th target value and the sum of the i-th **row** of matrix X must be less than or equal to the i-th availability value.

My question is:
Is it possible to algorithmically/algebraically generate such a matrix X? If possible, what would be a sensible approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the sum of absolute errors $\sum_k |\epsilon_k|$ subject to linear constraints by linearizing the objective and using a linear programming (LP) solver.

You can minimize the sum of squared errors $\sum_k \epsilon_k^2$ subject to linear constraints by using a quadratic programming (QP) solver.